# Run two commands on Visual Studio Code

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Code 1.7 with ASP.NET Core 1.1 and I have the following launch.json:

```
{
 "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": ".NET Core Launch (Web)",
      "type": "coreclr",
      "request": "launch",
      "preLaunchTask": "build",
      "program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.1/MVC.dll",
      "args": [],
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "launchBrowser": {
        "enabled": true,
        "args": "${auto-detect-url}",
        "windows": {
          "command": "cmd.exe",
          "args": "/C start ${auto-detect-url}"
        },
        "osx": {
          "command": "open"
        },
        "linux": {
          "command": "xdg-open"
        }
      },
      "env": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "sourceFileMap": {
        "/Views": "${workspaceRoot}/Views"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": ".NET Core Attach",
      "type": "coreclr",
      "request": "attach",
      "processId": "${command.pickProcess}"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is working but I also need to run two gulp tasks on launch:

```
gulp clearCssJs
gulp buildCssJs
```

I have the following tasks.json:

```
  {
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "dotnet",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": [],
    "tasks": [
    {
      "taskName": "build",
      "args": [ ],
      "isBuildCommand": true,
      "showOutput": "silent",
      "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
    }
  ]
}
```

So I need to have 2 gulp tasks in tasks.json and the dotnet build task.

Am I wrong? How can I do this?

**Update**

To clarify, I already have the following on my csproj:

```
<Target Name="Prepublish" BeforeTargets="PrepareForPublish" Condition=" '$(IsCrossTargetingBuild)' != 'true' ">
  <Exec Command="npm install" />
  <Exec Command="bower install" /> 
  <Exec Command="gulp clean" />
  <Exec Command="gulp build" />
</Target>  

<Target Name="PostpublishScript" AfterTargets="Publish" Condition=" '$(IsCrossTargetingBuild)' != 'true' ">
  <Exec Command="dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder $(TargetDir) --framework $(TargetFrameworkIdentifier),Version=$(TargetFrameworkVersion)" />
</Target>
```

So this allows to run the npm, bower and gulp tasks when publishing to the server ...

The point is what when running on my development machine and debugging ... I think it would be more appropriate to launch only the Gulp tasks and using Visual Studio Code and not having them inside the project file. No?

Comment: Create another tasks that combines the two tasks you need to run e.g. `gulp.task('css', ['clearCssJs', 'buildCssJs']);` or make the buildCssJs task depend on the clearCssJs task.

Comment: @Pawel The problem is not running clearCssJs and buildCssJs or only one. The problem is to run both with the dotnet task

Answer (score 0):

Probably what you need to look into is the `project.json`. It has a `scripts` section that can define a group of scripts that need to run before/after compiling, publishing, etc. For example:

`{
  "scripts": {
    "precompile": [ "gulp clearCssJs" ],
    "postcompile": [ "gulp buildCssJs" ]
  }
}`

I haven't tried it out by myself, but I believe it would work.

Comment: You can also run both in one step by doing: `"precompile": [ "gulp clearCssJs",  "gulp buildCssJs"]`. One caveat is that gulp needs to be installed globally. If you install it only locally you need to run gulp more or less like this: `../../node_modules/.bin/gulp/gulp.cmd'